# Emitting events from spring managed bean to listeners

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a event notifier in my Repository layer so I can add listeners. I am using Spring and I wonder if this a okey way of doing it? Or are there better ways to implement notifying/listeners in Spring?

```
@Repository
public class JdbcRepository {

    private List<InsertListener> insertListeners;

    public void insert(final SomeObject object) {
        // Ommited code for brewity
        for (InsertListener listener : insertListeners) {
            listener.notifiy(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Spring config xml

```
<bean id="jdbcRepository" class="mypackage.JdbcRepository">
    <property>
        <bean ref="myRepositoryListeners" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myRepositoryListeners" class="java.util.List">
    <constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <ref bean="..." />
        <ref bean="..." />
    </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
public class JdbcRepository {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;
    Collection<InsertListener> listeners;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listeners = context.getBeansOfType(InsertListener.class).values();
    }
...
```

context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="l1" class="InsertListener" />
<bean id="l2" class="InsertListener" />
<bean id="repo" class="JdbcRepository" />
```

Comment: Right, so the bottom approach that I suggested in the question is okey? And there is probably no way to do this with just annotations?

Comment: Nice! So you could choose between doing this (creates a little more coupling to Spring, with the App context injection) or configuring it in the xml? What would you do?

Comment: I would vote for annotations, I would also consider no-xml config

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for [Guava events](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained)  and some [Spring support](http://pmeade.blogspot.com/2012/06/using-guava-eventbus-with-spring.html) for it.